# passing multiple querystrings returning undefined in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to pass multiple query params back to my apiEnd point however its returning me `undefined`. I managed to get the strings that I needed without passing it to the `http.get` request.

So it splits the value from the input field into array objs, and this is returning me the array just fine but once I put it in the `get` request function its returns `/api/prodcutsundefined`

```
splitValue(event) {
    var idInputValue = this.productId.split(' ');
    console.log(idInputValue);
    if(idInputValue) {
        var ids = idInputValue;
        var queryString = "?";
        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            var id = ids[i];
            if (i > 0) {
                queryString += "&";
            }
            queryString += ("id="+id);
            console.log(queryString);
        }
    }
}
```

with the api end point passing the queryString back, seems like `this.queryString` is not being pass back in the `url`. How can I pass

```
getProduct() {
        this.http.get('http:../api/Products'+this.queryString)
        .map(response => response.text())
        .subscribe(data => {
            if(data) {
                // var productObj = JSON.parse(data);
                this.productId = JSON.parse(data).Id;

                var idInputValue = this.productId.split(' ');
                console.log(idInputValue);
                if(idInputValue) {
                    var ids = idInputValue;
                    var queryString = "?";
                    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                        var id = ids[i];
                        if (i > 0) {
                            queryString += "&";
                        }
                        this.queryString += ("id="+id);
                        console.log(queryString);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: instead of appending the query string to the url you should pass it as config object  get(url, [config]);
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get

Comment: can you show how in angular2?

Comment: I have not tested this but try like this 
this.http.get('http:../api/Products',{data: this.queryString})

Comment: doesn't accept it, it says not assignable to parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 2, the this.http.get() takes an object as a second parameter [( check this RequestOptionsArgs)](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/RequestOptionsArgs-interface.html)  
the search property of that object can be used to pass the url parameter [URLSearchParams object](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/URLSearchParams-class.html).